# Muxing a JPEG bitstream inside a TIFF container?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, libtiff

On my Linux system (Debian) I can decode and then re-encode JPEG to TIFF [using](https://superuser.com/questions/827606/use-ffmpeg-for-jpeg-to-tiff-conversion):

```
% ffmpeg -i input.jpeg -pix_fmt rgba output.tiff
```

Or even using libtiff-tools:

```
% convert -size 256x256 -depth 8 xc:white white.ppm
% ppm2tiff white.ppm white.tiff
% tiffcp -c jpeg white.tiff white.jpg.tiff
```

A JPEG compression (lossy process) is done internally during `tiffcp` operation.

But instead I want to do **lossless** muxing from JPEG into a TIFF container/format (and the opposite: extract JPEG bitstream from input TIFF/JPEG file). Can I do that using ffmpeg or other UNIX command line tool ? For example I can mux JPEG to M-JPEG [losslessly](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/7913/10558):

```
% ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input%03d.jpg -codec copy output.mjpeg
```

For reference, here is a typical TIFF/JPEG, how can I extract the raw JPEG bistream from it ?

```
% tiffinfo white.jpg.tiff
TIFF Directory at offset 0x430 (1072)
  Image Width: 256 Image Length: 256
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: JPEG
  Photometric Interpretation: YCbCr
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 256
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Reference Black/White:
     0:     0   255
     1:   128   255
     2:   128   255
  JPEG Tables: (574 bytes)
```

Comment: Do you want to add JPEG as page in TIFF?

Comment: I'd like to extract/encapsulate a JPEG bitstream inside a TIFF container. No JPEG compression involved, simple muxing codec inside a different container/format.

Comment: So you want to **create** TIFF and add there a JPEG, right?

Comment: This command may help: `convert image.jpg image.tiff`

Comment: @RomeoNinov that re-compresses the image, even when told to preserve the source compression (`-define tiff:preserve-compression=true`).

Comment: @StephenKitt, my understanding is by details ImageMagick do not apply any compression in TIFF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66994295/2908599 So it only decompress JPEG

Comment: @RomeoNinov ah yes, you’re right (at least, by default; `preserve-compression` causes it to compress data in TIFF files); but as I understand it, that’s not what malat is after — I understand the question as asking about a way to produce a TIFF file containing the same JPEG data as the original. The result of the conversion should have common binary data with the original, at least in part.

Comment: @StephenKitt, IMHO there is no (sample) way to do this. Except the case when JPEG is incorporated in meta information :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to extract JPEG from TIFF is as follow:

```
$ tiff2pdf -o white.jpg.tiff.pdf  white.jpg.tiff 
$ pdfimages -all white.jpg.tiff.pdf root
$ file root-000.jpg
root-000.jpg: JPEG image data
```

Since tiff2pdf man page states:

> If  the  input TIFF contains JPEG or single strip Zip/Deflate
> compressed information, and they are configured, then that is written
> to the PDF file without transcoding, unless the options of no
> compression and no passthrough are set.

The oppposite operation is slighty more complex than I originally thought since TIFF is not simply an "enveloppe" for the JPEG bitstream, as the huffman tables have been moved around:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749550/136285

Comment: That SO Q&A suggests that TIFF with type 6 compression *does* allow straightforward wrapping of JFIF in TIFF.